# How to get selected records under bulk edit functionality

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, bulkupdate, dynamics-crm-365-v9

I am working on 2016 on-premise MSCRM, I need to check each record in *bulk edit* and alert the user if something is wrong, I tried to alert it from my *update plugin* but only general msg appeared, now I'm trying to get all records selected in bulk edit, I googled and found this code :

```
var formType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();
if (formType == 6)
{
 //Read ids from dialog arguments
 var records = window.dialogArguments; 
 }
}
```

To use the bulk edit `formtype`  I need to add to event `onload` or `onchange` on customizations.xml the attribute : `BehaviorInBulkEditForm=“Enabled“` (unfortunately not so safe to edit this file) .

My questions:
which selected rows I'll get in onload and onchange event? ,I'm not sure where to use it in that case and if I'll get all the data I need.
Is there a better way/easy to get the data I need or to get the `formtype` - bulk edit.
Soon I'll be using MSCRM 365 is there any easier solution to this case in the 9.0 version ?

Comment: do you want to notify user when they use bulk edit and some records or something either went wrong or success?

Answer (score 0):

You can use method `window.getDialogArguments();` to get ids.

Here is my example:

I added an `onLoad` event for my form and enabled the `BehaviorInBulkEditForm`.

```
function onLoad(formContext) {
    var ids = window.getDialogArguments();
    console.log(ids);
}
```

The `ids` is an array, every element is a selected record id.

```
['{335A56B7-C717-ED11-B83F-00224856D931}', '{CBBDEBFB-C717-ED11-B83F-00224856D931}', '{3607EFC7-C717-ED11-B83F-00224856D931}', '{325A56B7-C717-ED11-B83F-00224856D931}']
```